# .change() method with visible selector issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have a change method for all visible select elements.

```
$('.select_elements:visible').change(function() {
  // function
)};
```

The above doesn't seem to run when I change the `select` element.  However if I write this it seems to work.

```
$('.select_elements').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
    // function
  }
)};
```

Can anyone explain this?  It wasted years (hours) of my life...

Comment: I'm sure you've read this already, but there are some rules that determine how and element's [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) is calculated. Please also post your example html that is not working.

Comment: Looks like there's a typo?  Not positive.  The last line should be });

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that the first version, where `:visible` is in the selector, only attaches the `change` event handler to the `select` elements that are visible in the DOM *when the page loads*.

The latter version attaches the event handler to *all* `select` elements, then checks their visibility at the time the event was fired.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I was started to assume.  Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Rory McCrossan's answer is an excellent explanation of what is happening. I am answering as well to propose a more performant and (to my mind at least) idiomatic solution than checking the visibility of elements in your change handler.

```
$(document).on('change', '.select_elements:visible', function () {
   // ...
});
```

This approach attaches only a single change handler to the document (you could pass it any parent of your .select_elements), which fires whenever the element that is changed matches the selector in the second argument. Since that selector is evaluated for every change event, it will also fire for visible elements that weren't visible when the handler was defined.

Comment: I will probably end up using this clean approach.  Thanks!